# Parent UIView not containing/clipping subviews

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, footer, addsubview

I am trying to add a footer to a UITableView. The table is a table of comments and the footer is where a user would enter his/her comments for posting. So Naturally, I define a UIView and inside the UIView, I add a UITextField and a UIButton. (left to right).

The problem is the UIView is not encompassing the children views. I want the children to be vertically centered inside the parent footer. My code is below. What am I doing wrong? Right now the parent view is showing as a thin slab in red. And overlapping the parent are the UITextField and the UIButon which are bigger in height than the parent.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static UIView *footer =nil;
    if (nil == footer) {
        footer =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 70)];
        footer.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];

        self.commentInputTextView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 50)];
        self.commentInputTextView.delegate=self;
        self.commentInputTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        self.commentInputTextView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        [footer addSubview:self.commentInputTextView];

        UIButton *post = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250, 0, 60, 50)];
        post.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        [post setTitle:@"Post" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [footer addSubview:post];
        [footer sizeToFit];
    }
    return footer;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set `clipsToBounds` to YES

```
footer.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Docs on this:

> A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the
>   bounds of the view.
>
> Declaration SWIFT var clipsToBounds: Bool OBJECTIVE-C
>   @property(nonatomic) BOOL clipsToBounds Discussion Setting this value
>   to YES causes subviews to be clipped to the bounds of the receiver. If
>   set to NO, subviews whose frames extend beyond the visible bounds of
>   the receiver are not clipped. The default value is NO.
>
> Import Statement import UIKit
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

---

To size the footer, you have to override the `UITableViewDelegate` method for footer heights:

> - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section Parameters tableView     The
>     table-view object requesting this information. section     An index
>     number identifying a section of tableView . Return Value A nonnegative
>     floating-point value that specifies the height (in points) of the
>     footer for section.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForFooterInSection:

Comment: clip to bounds is good but then my subviews are showing up as slabs within the parent slap. I need the parent view to grow to encompass the children. In any case, the height that is displayed is maybe 10 as opposed to 70. How do I fix that problem?